# Add classes to these links

Tags: theming, routes, hooks

I don't think this is hard at all but beeing a beginner at PHP and Drupal I need some help to do this.

I want to be able to add classes to my navigation elements that are outputted with this code:

```
function mytheme_menu_link__menu_block__1($variables) { 

$element = $variables['element'];

$sub_menu = '';

if ($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] != 'misc' && $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] != 'something') {

    if ($element['#below']) {
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }

    if ($element['#original_link']['in_active_trail'] == 0) {
        $output = ''.$element['#title'].'';
    }
    else {
        $output = ''.$element['#title'].'';
    }

    $link = l($output, $element['#href'], array('html' => TRUE));

    return $link;
}
else {
    return '';
}
}
```

If the menu item is active, it should have class X, otherwise class Y.
Could someone explain how I add this?

------------------------- Correct Answer -------------------------------

Here is the correct code that longboardnode helped me come up with.

```
function mytheme_menu_link__menu_block__1($variables) { 

$element = $variables['element'];
$sub_menu = '';

if ($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] != 'misc' && $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] != 'something') {

    if ($element['#below']) {
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }

    if ($element['#original_link']['in_active_trail'] == 0) {
        $output = $element['#title'];
        $class = 'activeClass';

    }
    else {
        $output = $element['#title'];
        $class = 'otherClass';

    }

    $link = l($output, $element['#href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => array($class)), 'html' => TRUE));

    return $link;
}
else {
    return '';
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question. If you want to add class to l(), then it must be an array, so your "$link=..." line would read

```
$link = l($output, $element['#href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => array('YOUR_CLASS_NAME')), 'html' => TRUE));
```

You can also read more and see other examples in [Drupal's l() documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what I want, I don't understand the syntax well enough. That line still gives me syntax error though.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'.

Thank's for helping.

Comment: I fixed it. You have to put class names as an array itself. I updated my original question with the answer.

Comment: Glad it helped! I did have a missing ) at the end to close the l() statement, revised in my answer. It should work now without the need to make HTML its own array. It's not a big deal but you might want to check it over. The third ) after your ($class))) effectively closes the third array in the l() statement and the l() documentation distinctly says that HTML should be an element inside l()'s third array ($options).

Comment: Johan, did you try my revised answer with the extra ) at end of line? As far as I can see you really shouldn't make HTML->TRUE a separate element in l() but should be part of the third element array.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it. It seems to work! Although making HTML -> TRUE into a seperate element seems to work just as well. At least I can't see any errors and I get my classes like I wanted. 

Anyway I'm going with your method since I trust you more than myself! :)

Comment: lol yeah very strange html->true worked as separate element! anyway glad ur issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert your desired class as attribute in your l() like:

```
if ($element['#original_link']['in_active_trail'] == 0) {
    $output = ''.$element['#title'].'';
    $class = 'activeClass';
}
else {
    $output = ''.$element['#title'].'';
    $class = 'otherClass';
}


l( $output, $element['#href'], array(
  'attributes' => array(
    'id' => '',
    'class' => $class,
  ),'html' => TRUE))
);
```

Comment: Thank's. Although I'm getting a syntax error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW". I can't see what's wrong, can you?

Comment: hmm sorry about that try array('html' => TRUE)))

Comment: Can't get it to work. How do you type out the entire l(); part?